# include templates in app-root conditionally based on the current url Angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am learning Angular and I want to include templates based on the current URL. I have two pages login and register which I don't want to include every time in the `app.component.html` of course. I have done a lot of search on google but have not found any solution yet.
This is how I tried to do it
`index.html`

```
<body>
    <input type="hidden" #currentUrl value="" id="current-url">
    <script>
        function getUrlParts(url) {
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;

            return {
                href: a.href,
                host: a.host,
                hostname: a.hostname,
                port: a.port,
                pathname: a.pathname,
                protocol: a.protocol,
                hash: a.hash,
                search: a.search
            };
        }
        document.getElementById('current-url').value = getUrlParts(window.location.href).pathname;
    </script>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

And this is `app.component.html`

```
<app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
<app-login *ngIf="document.getElementById('current-url').value == '/login'"></app-login>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And this is not working since document object is not accessible in `app.component.html`
Is there any workaround to achieve this? I understand that Angular is for one-page applications but except login and register my entire application will be one page.

**Update**

what I have understood from angular so far is that you include some components(navbar, sidebar, footer etc) shared by all pages in app.component.html and put router-outlet there as well to load different part of the page based on the url. But if I dont put anything in app.component.html except router-outlet then all the components will be loaded for each page I load. And if I put login/register components there as well they will be loaded everytime a page is loaded.

Comment: @Graham I have taken a look at the angular router a lot of times, first 2 months ago when and now when I am again in the same situation. But it does not mention anything about conditional including of templates. Maybe I am missing something?